Convert a reference to a reference to a value wrapped in a structure with the value of the reference
Is it possible to convert a reference to a reference to a value wrapped in a structure with the value of the reference? I could not give an implementation of the foo function, although I think this operation is safely possible. More specifically, my question would be as follows:

Is it possible to safely implement the foo function in the following code?
If the foo function is unsafe, on what grounds is it unsafe?

struct Foo<T> { bar: T }

// Can't compile
fn foo<'a,T>(x: &'a T) -> &'a Foo<T> {
    &Foo { bar: *x }
}


It's possible, though not safely:
// The `repr` attribute is important:
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: T,
}

fn foo<T>(x: &T) -> &Foo<T> {
    // SAFETY: This is okay because `Foo<T>` is guaranteed to have the same
    // layout as `T`.
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(x) }
}

repr(transparent) guarantees that a type will have the same layout as its only field, making it safe to transmute from one to the other and, by extension, from a reference to one to a reference to the other. The lifetime of x is also tied to the lifetime of the return value, so this can't be used to trick the borrow checker either.
A lot of work has been done on safe transmutes but I think it's pretty low on the priority list right now (rightly, I believe).
